# Power Query - best way to sub select?

Tags: powerquery

Suppose I have a column representing object type and another column representing object color. I want to remove blue and red fruits (example of object type)  but keep all other red and blue objects.

How can I acheive this in Power Query ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

## Just (un)select (not) matching rows

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Filtered = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not ([ObjectType] = "Fruit" and ([ObjectColor]="Red" or [ObjectColor]="Blue")))
in
    Filtered
```

Comment: This is much more straightforward, and therefore better, than the answer I proposed. *...No need for the merge.*

Comment: Thanks ! I knew there was an easy way ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

If you start with this:

[image]

You can merge the two columns together like this:

[image]

Then filter out the "Fruit,Blue" and "Fruit,Red":

[image]

Which yields this:

[image]

And you can then delete the "Merged" column to get this:

[image]

Here's the M code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ObjectType", type text}, {"ObjectColor", type text}}),
#"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Merged", each Text.Combine({[ObjectType], [ObjectColor]}, ","), type text),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Inserted Merged Column", each ([Merged] <> "Fruit,Blue" and [Merged] <> "Fruit,Red")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Merged"})
in
#"Removed Columns"
```